# bst segmentation fault search

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I'm working on BST assignment and I have made all the implementations; however, when I call the `bool insert(int i)` function, `segmentation fault(core dumped)` appears. Can you please find what I should change to get rid of this fault?

```
const treenode* find( const treenode* n, int i ){
    if(n->val==i)
        return n;
    else if(n->val<i)
        return find(n->right, i);    //if our key is less than given node it goes to the left node through recursion function
    else if(n->val>i)
        return find(n->left, i);   //the same thing here, if it is bigger - it goes right through recursion
    else
        return n;
}

treenode** find( treenode** n, int i ){
    if((*n)->val==i)
        return n;
    else if((*n)->val<=i)
        return find(&((*n)->right), i);
    else if((*n)->val>=i)
        return find(&((*n)->left), i);
    else
        return n;
}const treenode* find( const treenode* n, int i ){
    if(n== nullptr)
        return n;
    else if(n->val==i)
        return n;
    else if(n->val>i)
        return find(n->left, i);    //if our key is less than given node it goes to the left node through recursion function
    else if(n->val<i)
        return find(n->right, i);   //the same thing here, if it is bigger - it goes right through recursion
}

treenode** find( treenode** n, int i ){
    if((*n)->val==i)
        return n;
    else if((*n)->val<=i)
        return find(&((*n)->right), i);
    else if((*n)->val>=i)
        return find(&((*n)->left), i);
    else
        return n;
}

bool set::insert( int i ) {
        treenode** res=find(&tr, i);
        if(*res==nullptr) {
            *res = new treenode(i);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: @Swampy It is unclear how many functions find you have.:)

Comment: Also, `find` does not appear to mod the `n` argument, so why `**`?

Comment: No check for nullptr anywhere before it is used

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I was given two find fucntions, one for lookup and one for insertion and removal

Comment: @XSwampy You will only ever need one i.e, `treenode* find(treenode* n, int);`. This will cover all the cases because you don't ever modify the `pointer-to-treenode` instance anywhere inside of any of these functions. Moreover, these functions only serve the purpose of making the code longer and harder to read since, naturally they are all technically the same.

Comment: @Ruks I understand that it would be better to use one treenode* find, but the task of our assignment was to implement two find functions, so it is essential to make two functions :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function

```
treenode** find( treenode** n, int i ){
    if((*n)->val==i)
        return n;
    else if((*n)->val<=i)
        return find(&((*n)->right), i);
    else if((*n)->val>=i)
        return find(&((*n)->left), i);
    else
        return n;
}c
```

can invoke undefined behavior when the pointer `*n`  is equal to `nullptr` that is when the binary search tree is empty.

The function can look the following way

```
treenode ** find( treenode **n, int i )
{
    if ( *n == nullptr )
    {
        return n;
    }
    else if ( i < ( *n )->val )
    {
        return find( &( *n )->left, i );
    }
    else if ( ( *n )->val < i )
    {
        return find( &( *n )->right, i );
    }
    else
    {
        return n;
    }
}
```

and the other function find that shall be a constant member function can look like

```
const treenode * find( treenode *n, int i ) const
{
    if ( n == nullptr )
    {
        return n;
    }
    else if( i < n->val )
    {
        return find( n->left, i );
    }
    else if( n->val < i )
    {
        return find( n->right, i );
    }
    else
    {
        return n;
    }
}
```

I suppose that the constructor used in this statement

```
*res = new treenode(i);
```

sets the data members `left` and `right` to `nullptr`.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works, special respect from Kazakhstan

Comment: @xSwampy To c;lose the question select the best answer.:)